# How to show my app icon in user's contact app like WhatsApp and skype does?

Tags: flutter, contacts

I want to **show my app icon in the users contact app** if a particular user is registered. So far I have found nothing on the web that would point me towards a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to give more contexts about your question. But I am imagine you should probably use a listview in which each cell has a image on the right side. The images in each cell can be controlled by a flag, depends on the flag you can show whatever icons you like.

Comment: I know how to visually represent the listTile, What I am asking is How do I make My app icon  reach inside the USERS DEFAULT CONTACTS app, and then show it?